# Debian server intermittently fails to boot, possibly linked to MD/RAID - what can I do to investigate?

Tags: debian, mdadm

Occasionally (1 in 60 boots), one of our debian (2.6.32-45) servers fails to boot:

The output from the failed boot ends here:

```
...
[    7.831991] raid6: using algorithm sse2x4 (11665 MB/s)
[    7.839760] md: raid6 personality registered for level 6
[    7.839838] md: raid5 personality registered for level 5
[    7.839915] md: raid4 personality registered for level 4
[    7.853452] md: raid10 personality registered for level 10       <<<<<<< last line of output
```

Comparing this to a dmesg log from a 'good' boot:

```
...
[    7.737313] md: raid6 personality registered for level 6
[    7.737314] md: raid5 personality registered for level 5
[    7.737315] md: raid4 personality registered for level 4
[    7.749987] md: raid10 personality registered for level 10       <<<<<<<< equivalent line
[    7.752653] mdadm: sending ioctl 1261 to a partition!
[    7.752655] mdadm: sending ioctl 1261 to a partition!
[    7.753571] mdadm: sending ioctl 1261 to a partition!
[    7.753574] mdadm: sending ioctl 1261 to a partition!
[    7.753769] mdadm: sending ioctl 1261 to a partition!
[    7.753771] mdadm: sending ioctl 1261 to a partition!
[    7.753975] mdadm: sending ioctl 1261 to a partition!
[    7.753978] mdadm: sending ioctl 1261 to a partition!
[    7.754322] mdadm: sending ioctl 1261 to a partition!
[    7.754325] mdadm: sending ioctl 1261 to a partition!
...
```

I'm assuming the hang is caused by 'mdadm: sending ioctl 1261 to a partition!' but what can I do to investigate this further?

Comment: The kernel is seriously old I would look into upgrading that first since that kind of RAID is a kernel module. (3.8.5 is the current kernel version)

Comment: The kernel version is locked down and we can't change it. We're still investigating but we suspect a hardware issue and may end up swapping boards to pinpoint the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've pinpointed the issue to the RAID1 and RAID10 modules. The issue has been fixed in later Debian Builds.

The commit is here:
https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/d6b42dcb995e6acd7cc276774e751ffc9f0ef4bf

Answer (score 0):

`mdadm: sending ioctl 1261 to a partition!`

This warning can be ignore, it display has been removed in more recent releases.
Maybe you have a disk failure but not about this message